# How to combine two partitions?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, disk, move-partition

I installed Linux Mint in a dual boot alongside Windows 11, however now I am trying to get completely rid off Windows 11, however I haven't been able to combine the two partitions that I used for personal data storage (one of them is empty, so no need of keeping files).

This is what my partitions look like on lsblk:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1 259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1o1
│       259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5
│       259:2    0  27,9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p6
│       259:3    0   5,7G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p7
│       259:4    0    65G  0 part /media/user/
262f
└─nvme0n1p2
        259:5    0 139,6G  0 part
```

I would like to combine the 'nvme0n1p2' and 'nvme0n1p7', I don't know if that could be possible as I haven't been able to do it on GParted.

Comment: unlikely that those partitions would occupy sequential space on the device

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`? If `nvme0n1p2` is after `nvme0n1p7` without any partitions inbetween, then you should be able to remove `nvme0n1p2` and make `nvme0n1p7` larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two partitions only if they are adjacent. If they are not adjacent, you can always use LVM to initialize each partition as a Physical Volume, add the two Physical Volumes to a Volume Group, and create a Logical Volume from the Volume Group; then format the Logical Volume as usual.

The commands would be more or less this:

```
pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p7
pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p2
vgcreate myvg /dev/nvme0n1p7
vgextend myvg /dev/nvme0n1p2
lvcreate -L 204G -n mylv myvg
mkfs -t xfs /dev/myvg/mylv
```

Note that this will wipe the content of both partitions, so if they contain any data you want to keep, backup the data onto another device before proceeding.

Comment: `pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p7` will reformat `/dev/nvme0n1p7`, this looks like a partition that OP probably wants to keep the data on, given that it's mounted.

Comment: @Torin Duly noted. I have added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: Actually it could be started with only using nvme0n1p2, data moved there (139,6G >= 65G), then nvme0n1p7 gets formated as a PV, then vgextend, lvextend, xfs_growfs/resize2fs ... (avoids the need of an other device).